# How to put the <p> content inline with the <label>?

Tags: html, label, inline, text-indent

I run into a css issue.
I have a form, and inside it I want to show a label and some info in each line. 
The html for the form is:

```
<form class="form_dialog">
</br>
<label>Status: </label>
<span><img src="images/check.png" alt="check mark" width="16" height="16"/></span>
</br></br>
<label>Type: </label>
<span>V1</span>
</br></br>
<label>Description: </label>
<div class="sp">16 Nodes - Test for long description.
This system is good in all cases. Max length is 100.</div>
</form>
```

The css for all the tags are:

```
form.form_dialog {float: left; clear: left;}

.form_dialog div {float:left; clear:left}
.form_dialog label {
    display: block; float: left; 
    width: 12.0em; min-height: 2.0em; text-align: right;
}

.form_dialog span {
    margin-left: 3.0em;
}

div.sp {
     display:inline;
     margin-left:3em;
     margin-right:3em;
     width:70%;
}
```

My prob here is that for the description info, I want to keep the text lines indented(each line starts from the same position) as well as inline with label. But cannot achieve it.
Any one can help on this? Thanks.

Comment: FYI `</br>` should be `<br/>` (it's an _empty_ tag not a _closing_ tag).

Comment: This looks like tabular data. Why aren't you using a table? (If it's because "tables are evil"—that's not true if you're actually using tables _to present tabular data_).

Comment: @IgnisErus - You don't think it's a list of name-value pairs, then?

Comment: @Alohci - Sure, you could think of it that way—but I don't think this fits as a [definition list](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#h-10.3) if that's what you're suggesting. However, I'd say it'd be just as correct to display this data in tabular format as it would be in list format, with each "label" being a `<th>` cell and the descriptive text being a `<td>` cell.

Comment: Also, `<label>` tags are supposed to be labels for form fields, not for random text. (If used correctly, then when you click on the label it actual shifts focus to the associated form field. E.g. clicking on the label for a checkbox toggles the check-mark in the checkbox.)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a table. You could use a table, or use two seperate  elements, placed side by side inside of a containing .

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="formContainer">
   </div>
   <div class="textContainer">
   </div>
</div>
```

Then float each container and align your text using CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Trendy, also, since you starting using `span` tag, you should just use the `span`

```
<span>16 Nodes - Test for long description.
This system is good in all cases. Max length is 100.</span>
```